# Can I call SSL_write() if SSL_read() is blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ?

Tags: ssl, openssl, nonblocking

My program was developed based on the OpenSSL(blocking mode), I'd like to refactor  it to a non-blocking one. It calls SSL_read() in a thread with a SSL object, and calls SSL_write() in another thread with the same object.

I studied the OpenSSL non-blocking mode from the book ["Network Security with OpenSSL"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600270X), there is a example(data_transfer) for this mode.

```
for (;;)
{
    /* check the readability and writability */
    check_availability(A, &can_read_A, &can_write_A, B, &can_read_B, &can_write_B);

    /* write_waiton_read_A: SSL_write was blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ
     * write_waiton_write_A: SSL_write was blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE
     * read_waiton_write_A: SSL_read was blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE
     * read_waiton_read_A: SSL_read was blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ
     */

          /* not in the middle of a write on A */
    if (!(write_waiton_read_A || write_waiton_write_A) && 
            (A2B_len != BUF_SIZE) &&
            /* 
             * a. A is readable.
             * b. the read was blocked for "WANT_WRITE" and A 
             *    is writable  now.
             */
            (can_read_A || (can_write_A && read_waiton_write_A)))
    {
        read_waiton_read_A = 0;
        read_waiton_write_A = 0;

        code = SSL_read(A, A2B + A2B_len, BUF_SIZE - A2B_len);
        switch (SSL_get_error(A, code))
        {
            ...
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            read_waiton_read_A = 1;
            break;

         case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
             read_waiton_write_A = 1;
             break;
            ...
        }
    }

    ...

          /* not in the middle of a read on A */
    if (!(read_waiton_write_A || read_waiton_read_A) &&
        have_data_B2A &&
        /*
         * a. A is writable.
         * b. the write was blocked for "WANT_READ" and A 
         *    is readable now.
         */
        (can_write_A || (can_read_A && write_waiton_read_A)))
    {
        write_waiton_read_A = 0;
        write_waiton_write_A = 0;

        code = SSL_write(A, B2A, B2A_len);
        switch (SSL_get_error(A, code))
        {
            ...
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            write_waiton_read_A = 1;
            break;

        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            write_waiton_write_A = 1;
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I conclude from the code above that I must wait for SSL_read() to be completed if it's blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, I can't call SSL_write() although A is writable on this condition.

Is it right? I'd like to my program can read and send data simultaneously, can I call SSL_write() if SSL_read() is blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, but all you will get is `SSL_WANT_READ` again.

Hard to understand why you are even contemplating this.

Comment: I know that SSL_read() will get SSL_WANT_READ again if it was blocked for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ.  How about SSL_write() if SSL_read() was blocked? My program's connection is a long-lived one, and I'd like to write data to the SSL instance although it was blocked in SSL_read(), so the throughput won't decrease.